# Error while creating bug in Bugzilla using Java

Tags: java, xml-rpc, bugzilla

while trying to create a new bug in bugzilla, i am getting an error 
"You must log in before using this part of Bugzilla"

Code looks like

```
`HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    XmlRpcClient rpcClient = new XmlRpcClient();
    XmlRpcCommonsTransportFactory factory = new XmlRpcCommonsTransportFactory(rpcClient);
    XmlRpcClientConfigImpl config = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();

    factory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
    rpcClient.setTransportFactory(factory);
    config.setServerURL(new URL("http://192.168.0.203/xmlrpc.cgi"));
    rpcClient.setConfig(config);

    // map of the login data
    Map<String, String> loginMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    loginMap.put("login", "bugzilla.admin@abcd.com");
    loginMap.put("password", "bugzilla@admin");
    loginMap.put("rememberlogin", "Bugzilla_remember");

    // login to bugzilla
    Object loginResult = rpcClient.execute("User.login", new Object[]{loginMap});
    System.err.println ("loginResult=" + loginResult);

    // map of the bug data
    Map<String, String> bugMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    bugMap.put("product", "Demo");
    bugMap.put("component", "Demo_project");
    bugMap.put("summary", "Bug created for test");
    bugMap.put("description", "This is text ");
    bugMap.put("version", "unspecified");
    bugMap.put("op_sys", "Windows");
    bugMap.put("platform", "PC");
    bugMap.put("priority", "P2");
    bugMap.put("severity", "Normal");
    bugMap.put("status", "NEW");

    // create bug
    Object createResult = rpcClient.execute("Bug.create", new Object[]{bugMap});
    System.err.println("createResult = " + createResult);
 `
```

At first i am able to login and the response I get is-: loginResult={id=1, token=1-AJ4uG13zlJ}
 but when creating a new bug error occurs

```
`Exception in thread "main" org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException: You must log in before using this part of Bugzilla.
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.readResponse(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:197)
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:156)
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcHttpTransport.java:143)
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientWorker.execute(XmlRpcClientWorker.java:56)
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:167)
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:137)
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:126)
at com.abcd.BugCreator2.main(BugCreator2.java:52)`
```

Why do I get this error of login again, when I am already logged in.

Edit-:

The above code works fine when tried on https://bugzilla.mozilla.org
It seems there is some problem while configuration of Bugzilla on local server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all thanks to you i was searching code just like yours...

and if you still get that error you should know that you also need to send login and password parameters for create method.

just try like this ..

add this

```
bugMap.put("login", "bugzilla.admin@abcd.com");
bugMap.put("password", "bugzilla@admin");
```

before this

```
bugMap.put("product", "Demo");
bugMap.put("component", "Demo_project");
bugMap.put("summary", "Bug created for test");
bugMap.put("description", "This is text ");
bugMap.put("version", "unspecified");
bugMap.put("op_sys", "Windows");
bugMap.put("platform", "PC");
bugMap.put("priority", "P2");
bugMap.put("severity", "Normal");
bugMap.put("status", "NEW");
```